# Implement an Interface which extends Parcelable

Tags: java, android, bundle

I want to send a `listener` from an `adapter` to `fragment`. As android suggests not to use constructors i'm sending listener through `setArguments()`.

I'm unable to `implement` this listener properly.

This is mycode

**Listener:**

```
public interface DiscoverFragmentListener extends Parcelable{

    void onSwitchToNextFragment();
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
public final class DiscoverpageListener implements DiscoverFragmentListener {
            @Override
            public void onSwitchToNextFragment() {
                mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(mFragmentAtPos0)
                        .commit();
                if (mFragmentAtPos0 instanceof DummySectionFragment) {
                    Button_Description frag = new Button_Description();
                    Bundle basket = new Bundle();
                    basket.putParcelable("listener",listener);
                    frag.setArguments(basket);
                    mFragmentAtPos0 = frag;
                } else { // Instance of NextFragment
                    DummySectionFragment frag = new DummySectionFragment();
                    Bundle basket = new Bundle();
                    basket.putParcelable("listener",listener);
                    frag.setArguments(basket);
                    mFragmentAtPos0 = frag;
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public int describeContents() {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

            }
        }
```

**DummySectionFragment:**

```
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment{



        private DiscoverFragmentListener discoverFragmentListener;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.discover_fragment, container, false);

            discoverFragmentListener = getArguments().getParcelable("listener");
return rootView;
```

**I'm getting this error:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Parcelable android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Help me out!

Thanks!

Comment: Call a setter method on the fragment, supplying the listener. You cannot make a listener be `Parcelable`. Or, better yet, pull the listener from the activity in `onAttach()`.

Comment: If you have no data then why to use Parcelable. Parcelable is used when you have some data in the object and you want to serialize it(pass to next activity or fragment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you a better idea :
Parcelable is just like Serializable.

It means when you want to pass a custom object containing some state you need to make it Parcelable.

Here you are trying to achieve something else. You just want to set a callback.
As suggested in the comment you can use setCallback / onAttach method to achieve this.

Comment: Here in this case i have to implement DiscoverFragmentListener inside an viewpager adapter. So i want to know how should i call this in the fragment.

Comment: You have multiple options here. If you want a better design then you might consider using a event bus. Follow this link : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-EventBusOtto/article.html                     But say u just want to get the things done, keep a reference of fragment in your main activity from switchToMainFragment function.

Comment: Thanks. I solved it by calling adapter and then it's methods in my fragment.